# Need to figure out conio.h for a book program, which Idk how to

Tags: c++, visual-studio, input, conio

I'm writing a book program that enables the user to Add and Find books to a library. Now, I need to figure out how to receive keyboard input from the user using conio.h/any other alternative. So that if the user presses '1', the AddMenu() gets called, but if he/she presses 2, FindMenu() gets called. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


class Book {
public:
    string title; //title of da book
    double sepnum; //unique identification code (ex. 1111, 0009, etc.)
};

void AddMenu() {

    Book book1;

    cout << "********ADD MENU********" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Book Name:" << endl;
    cin >> book1.title;
    cout << "Enter Book Callsign (Ex: 0001, 5672):" << endl;
    cin >> book1.sepnum;
    cout << "Succesfully added" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "************************" << endl;

}

void FindMenu() {

}

int main()
{
    cout << "**********MENU**********" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "1. Add Book" << endl;
    cout << "2. Find Book" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "************************" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want [`_getch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-160)?

Comment: I would skip the `conio.h`  and just use standard `c++`. Meaning use `std::cin >> someCharVar;` and have the user press enter.

Comment: Looks like you don't need `conio.h`.  Try removing it.

Comment: SomeCharVar would work, but I have two parameters (i.e. Two Functions) and a specific char needs to be entered for each function. So I considered conio.h

Comment: Get the `char` then use a switch / case there are many examples of what you are trying to do on this site.

Comment: Unrelated: don't use `double` for unique identifiers. Trying to compare `double`s for exact equality will only cause trouble. Use `int` or `long int` if you expect integers, or use `string` if you want to preserve the entire input as-is with decimals, leading zeroes, extra letters and so on.

Comment: According to your description, I wonder if you want to call different functions based on user input? If so, I suggest you could try to use [unordered_map Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/unordered-map-class?view=msvc-160)